# cardano-cli submit error: ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW

Tags: cardano-cli, nft, transaction

I have a problem when submitting a transaction using cardano-cli 1.33.

This is my transaction:

*cardano-cli transaction build-raw 

--tx-in 0e2a21444b1aeeba7cb10f21d221ae7ff844f0b4f8c444e557cd8d4fd1396cc2#1 

--tx-in e4dcdfd68ea1cbf52425f775c92a83404652f9be9b24b6c8d9cf53d9ba563d90#0 

--tx-out addr1q96x3lat2putrufnr4nml4dpaeflmk9f0necnwags593fyczhes4kfnypptyuqsm824w5mhx4p4venlcc4l8w6rlsdzskzcvwu+21793799+"1 7ed6bfc18a525bac4b0891c5fc106e8cf06ccfcf2926bf58a35b55e4.005400490054004f0030003200350030" 

--mint="1 7ed6bfc18a525bac4b0891c5fc106e8cf06ccfcf2926bf58a35b55e4.005400490054004f0030003200350030" 

--minting-script-file /home/node/Desktop/test/src/utilities/../keys/tmp/script_4wtn6rz8h.json 

--metadata-json-file /home/node/Desktop/test/src/utilities/../keys/tmp/metadata_fab5bmmo5.json 

--invalid-hereafter 82089724 

--invalid-before 0 

--fee 206201 

--out-file /home/node/Desktop/test/src/utilities/../keys/tmp/tx_d9ns8yg52.raw*

This is my mint script:

*{
"type": "all",
"scripts": [
{
"slot": 82089724,
"type": "before"
},
{
"keyHash": "c4aae7aca5e060793f24fbf860f6538fce187fe28675d7d43481d93d",
"type": "sig"
}
]
}*

and this is the error that i get:

*Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (ScriptWitnessNotValidatingUTXOW (fromList [ScriptHash "7ed6bfc18a525bac4b0891c5fc106e8cf06ccfcf2926bf58a35b55e4"])))])*

Any idea? Let me know if you need more info.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Would need your signing command to be able to fully assess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your signing command it's difficult to discern what you're doing wrong. Can you confirm you are referencing the policy skey in your signing command? --signing-key-file keys/policy.skey

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the transaction pattern found [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts) toward the end of the page. It worked for me.

You need to add

```
--mainnet \
--alonzo-era \
--witness-override 2 \
```

You can probably drop the --invalid-hereafter, unless you think you specifically need that. Remove the --fee. Also, make sure your invalid-hereafter is in the future. You may only need 1 tx-in as long as that utxo has enough to cover your transaction.